# Using distinct with group by and calculating sum

Tags: postgresql

I have this given table at the top of the picture.
I am looking for a SQL query that returns below table.

Each ProjectID has a unique Manager but not every field is filled out.

[image]

Can someone help me?

The bills should be summed together by project ID, the manager has to be displayed for every unique project ID.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `min` or `max` to aggregate the manager, since such aggregates will skip NULL values:

```
SELECT projectid,
       min(manager) AS manager,
       sum(bill) AS sum_of_bill
FROM tab
GROUP BY projectid;
```